# Add cell to UITableView if textfield of previous cell is filled in

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` in my `ViewController`. Every cell contains a `textfield` where someone can enter new text (a to do list). Now, I want to add a new cell, which already contains a new `textfield`, only if the `textfield` of the previous cell contains text.

Currently I use a `UIButton` to add a new cell and this works and resizes the table view so all cells are visible, but I want this to be automated after filling in the previous cell so it becomes more user friendly.

[This is what my Storyboard looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9cik.png)

And this is the code I currently use to add a new row:

```
    @IBAction func btnAddRow_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {

    toDoTableView.beginUpdates()
    amountCells.append("")
    self.toDoTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: self.amountCells.count - 1, section: 0)] , with: .automatic)
    toDoTableView.endUpdates()
    tblHeight.constant = toDoTableView.contentSize.height

}
```

Any idea on how I can accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: I have tried to use EditingDidEnd**

```
    class TextFieldsCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtToDo: UITextField!

    @IBAction func txtToDo_EditingDidEnd(_ sender: Any) {
            if(!(txtToDo.text?.isEmpty)! {
                print("Insert Code to Add New Row")
            }
        }
}
```

When I do this, I cannot access the `toDoTableView` from my `ViewController`. Another issue this might result in is that when there already are 5 rows and the first one is simply edited, another row will insert while I would not want that.

Comment: In textfield didend editing.. you need to check that textfield is fillup or not? if it is fillup add one row in numberofRowInSection and reload table.

Comment: @HardikThakkar I have tried to use DidEndEditing and then checked if the textfield was empty or not, however this is in my subclass for the cell (because that's where the textfield is), where I can not access toDoTableView..

Comment: @PennyWise, You need to check this in your ViewController and it becomes easy

Comment: @Kuldeep tried that too. But when I add the textfield in my ViewController, I get the error: Illegal Configuration: The txtToDo outlet from the ViewController to the UITextField is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content. - which is why I set this up in a subclass of the cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check, whether textfield is empty or not in viewController itself. You just confirm the delegate for textfield from **storyboard** and in **cellForRowAt** and give the tag to that text field

e.g,

```
cell.yourTextField.delegate = self
cell.yourTextField.tag = indexPath.row
```

and check the textfield is empty or not in **textField delegate** method. Create object of cell in method like

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
     rowBeingEditedInt = textField.tag
     let indexPath = IndexPath(row:rowBeingEdited! , section:0 )
     let cell = yourTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! yourTableViewCell
  // check cell.yourtextField.text isempty and do your condition
 }
```

Comment: I have implemented this code, changed it a bit and it works. Thanks! The only issue I now have is, when editing ends, a row is inserted even if there already is a row underneath it. So if I edit a previous row, another one is inserted as well.I'll take a look at the other answers to figure out how to fix this.

Comment: you can set flag in object to check whether that cell is already edited or not. If flag is 'true' then just update cell or else if it is 'false' then insert new one.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to you `textfield` delegate and Replace `tableview` with your tableview name

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField!){

    var cell: UITableViewCell = textField.superview.superview as UITableViewCell
    var table: UITableView = cell.superview as UITableView
    let textFieldIndexPath = table.indexPathForCell(cell)
    if textFieldIndexPath.row == (yourdataArray.count - 1)
    {
        print("came to last row")

        if ((textField.text?.count)! > 0){

            print("text available")

            toDoTableView.beginUpdates()
            amountCells.append("")
            self.toDoTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row:
                self.amountCells.count - 1, section: 0)] , with: .automatic)
            toDoTableView.endUpdates()
            tblHeight.constant = toDoTableView.contentSize.height
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is in `Objective C` or in `Swift`?

Comment: This appears to be Swift 2; OP looks like he's using Swift 3 or 4.

Comment: Swift 4 indeed. How do I convert this?

Comment: @JohnAyers, `origin`, `point`, `indexpath` and other are also in Objective C.

Comment: @PennyWise I've Updated the Code! check now

Comment: `let textFieldIndexPath = table.indexPathForCell(cell)` should be `table.indexPath(for: cell)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

In `cellForRowAt` method set `UITableViewCell` textField delegate first.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:TableViewCell = self.tblvw.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    cell.txtField.delegate = self
    cell.txtField.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.txtField?.text = amountCells[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

In `textFieldDidEndEditing` you just need to check below and based on that you perform your further task.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    return textField.resignFirstResponder()
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField.text?.count == 0 || textField.tag != self.amountCells.count - 1 {

    }
    else {
        self.tblvw.beginUpdates()
        amountCells.append("")
        self.tblvw.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: self.amountCells.count - 1, section: 0)] , with: .automatic)
        self.tblvw.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it eventually by combining answers from @Mauli and @Vicky_Vignesh / @Kuldeep.

```
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    let rowBeingEditedInt = textField.tag
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row:rowBeingEditedInt , section:0 )
    let cell = toDoTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TextFieldsCell
    let table: UITableView = cell.superview as! UITableView

    let textFieldIndexPath = table.indexPath(for: cell)
    if textFieldIndexPath?.row == (amountCells.count - 1) {

        if(!(cell.txtToDo.text?.isEmpty)!) {
            toDoTableView.beginUpdates()
            amountCells.append("")
            self.toDoTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: self.amountCells.count - 1, section: 0)] , with: .automatic)
            toDoTableView.endUpdates()
            tblHeight.constant = toDoTableView.contentSize.height
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks guys! Much appreciated.